# Android studio error - Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: android-emulator

Emulator error

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
```

Answer (score 36):

If you're trying to build your app to an emulated Android device, it might need to be cold-booted. Go to Tools -> AVD Manager, and on the Virtual Device you're trying to use, click the drop-down arrow to the far right and select "Cold Boot Now".

Give the emulator a few moments to start, and if it does so without error, try building your app again and see if it now loads properly.

Comment: Not only this solution was a life saver it also prevented an anger burst.

Comment: thats not permanent solution. Problem will repeat and you need to repeat the step again and again but it is time consuming

Answer (score 5):

I Spent 4 to 5 HOURS to solve this issues and tried my possible solution, but no Luck, but FINALLY, I did it from myself, So may be it will help anybody in future.

**What i did :**

1. i Changed My Emulator Targeting Hardware/Phone From Pixels to Nexus 5x (Not Any Pixel hardware/Phone worked for me.
2. i Changed System Image From **R** (Api Level 30) to **Q** (Api Level 29). And its Done!!

**i am attaching some reference screenshots to better understand.**

- Selecting Hardware Image[image: 1]
- Selecting System Image, Under **x86 Image Tab**[image: 2]
- Final Result, After Emulator Created Sucessfully[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

There are times when i also suffer from the same problem. Cold Reboot has always worked for me. Go to your AVD manager then select the device you have to reboot. Then click on the drop down icon and select cold reboot. Wait for a while your VD should work fine now. In case it doesn't create another VD that should do the trick.