# emulator runs fine but app shows white screen, error is below

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

Good day to all.

I'm following the teacher's notes and am ready to run the app in android studio 3.6.1. The emulator runs fine but when I open the app I get a white screen. At the bottom of the android windows, I see the following error.

```
Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
```

I have searched this website and google for the problem. I'm trying to figure out if this is a coding problem or something to do with android studio.

what I tried is in this link... [emulator problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined)

Any help to understand the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually reinstalled android and started the project again only to find that the possible solution was to enable usb debugging on the phone. To do this you go to settings - click on about phone - click version number several times to enable developer mode. Then go back 1 step and click on developer mode. Enable usb debugging.

I think this could have fixed the problem so if you having a similar problem to me, please try this.