# emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:1: 'GL_OES_EGL_image_external' : extension is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

New and learning android studio, trying to create a project which can access user's location but can't do it because my emulator is allowing to change/update users location. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lcqq.png)

All I can see in the location tab is this black screen and the following log:

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:1: 'GL_OES_EGL_image_external' : extension is not supported
 ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***<code/><code>
- ifdef GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
-extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable
-extension GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced : enable
-endif

-ifndef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
-define highp mediump
-endif
-line 1
-extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
varying highp vec2 uv;uniform samplerExternalOES textureSampler;
uniform bool swizzle;uniform highp float opacity;void main() {   highp vec4 tmpFragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, uv);   tmpFragColor.a *= opacity;   gl_FragColor = swizzle ? tmpFragColor.bgra 
: tmpFragColor;}
*** ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: Could not link shader program:
 "" ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
ANGLE: D3D11: rx::Renderer11::generateConfigs
```

The black screen is only on the location tab, rest are working fine.
Please can anyone help.

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solutions yet? Thanks

Comment: Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined)