# Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-cardview, android-assets, dashboard-designer

I'm trying to implement a dashbord in android studio from this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6CfaWW7G5Q&feature=youtu.be
I did exactely the same things just replaced the home activity by main activity but 
When I run the app, it's successfully installed but it doesn't start and I get this as Error:

```
Gradle build finished in 10 s 569 ms

Install successfully finished in 41 s 368 ms.

Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
            android:layout_width="203dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Banking"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your bank activities"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/ideas_card"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpink"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_lightbulb_outline_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Ideas"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check your bank activities"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundgreen"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_control_point_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check your bank activities"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundyellow"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Links"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your bank activities"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check your bank activities"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined