# Android Studio Emulator Affected by Anti-Virus Program (McAfee)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, antivirus, mcafee

I run my emulator and it showed me this on the build output:

```
Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
```

```
C:\Users\...\.gradle
C:\Users\...\.AndroidStudio3.5\system
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

It redirected me to this website: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact
. I excluded Android Studio in my McAfee real-time scanning but after I run my emulator again it's very slow compared to before I had the warning.

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined