# I am having an error when run code in android studio

Tags: java, android

I dont know why it has error when run this code in emulator with android studio.

> The detail error :  SA    Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68:
>   Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of
>   undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))

```
package com.example.zingmp3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button nextButton, previousButton, playButton, pauseButton;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private TextView timeCurrent, timeTotal, nameSong;
    private int index;
    private int position = 3;
    private Handler handler;
    ArrayList<Song> songs;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findById();
        addSong();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, songs.get(position).getFile());

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void findById() {
        this.nextButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        this.previousButton = findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
        this.playButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        this.timeCurrent = findViewById(R.id.timeCurrent);
        this.timeTotal = findViewById(R.id.totalTime);
        this.seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        this.nameSong = findViewById(R.id.nameSong);
    }

    private void addSong() {
        Song song1 = new Song("Mot Cu Lua", R.raw.song1);
        Song song2 = new Song("So rang anh con yeu em", R.raw.soranganhyeuem);
        Song song3 = new Song("Tinh sau thien thu muon loi", R.raw.tinhsauthienthu);

        songs.add(song1);
        songs.add(song2);
        songs.add(song3);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298563/android-studio-error-cannot-read-property-update-of-undefined

Comment: I tried but it didnt work for me

Comment: when I comment all function, and only addSong actived, the "app keep stoping" displayed in emulator. I guess error happend with addSong function

Comment: replace `R.raw.*` with `getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.your_resource_id)`  in addSongs() and try

Comment: You didn't initialize the `songs` field

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
    ArrayList<Song> songs;
```

to this

```
    ArrayList<Song> songs= new ArrayList<>();
```

or define it in onCreate ...

```
songs= new ArrayList<>();
```